# Using Constraint Layout for Custom views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using the drag and drop functionality in the layout editor to try and get 4 image buttons aligned in a kite shape. This is the layout I am trying to achieve, currently using `ImageButton` but I will change to the circular image view to suit the layout later.
[image: Screen grab of the layout goal]

Can anyone help me to achieve this. Please find my XML below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/ongoing_call_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:layout_below="@id/contact_number_tv"
    android:layout_above="@id/calculator_layout">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/not_billable_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/billable_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/not_billable_imgBtn"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="105dp" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/decide_later_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this buddy, and make your own adjustments.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ongoing_call_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:layout_below="@id/contact_number_tv"
    android:layout_above="@id/calculator_layout">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.32"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/not_billable_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/billable_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.66"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/decide_later_imgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/not_billable_imgBtn" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[See the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TkeR.png)

But perhaps your real problem is that the constrainLayout is not your root element, and you should set a fixed height instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: You could use vertical bias instead of margins.

Comment: deadfish you're correct, but as you can see he is using layout_heigt="wrap_content" in parent container, so vertical bias won't work here.

Comment: Marked as correct answer because it is the closest solution to the question asked. Seeing that `ConstraintLayout` is cumbersome to use I went ahead and used a `TableLayout` with three rows and three columns